# How to specify EntityListener at runtime in JPA 2.1 and JavaSE?

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, cdi

I am doing some modernization work on a mature project with a DB that isn't really ORM friendly.  Prior work was in Java but used JDBC.

I am testing the waters with JPA 2.1 (EclipseLink) on a standalone program.   For this program, my explicit DB needs are pretty simple and JPA in SE is doing OK.    I am not totally new to JPA, but most prior work have been toys.

One problem a ran into:  an entity I am using has an attribute that comes from a DB column (via named native query), and that attribute must be prefixed with a value/string that comes from the command line of the program; before the attribute is really ready to use.

In 'old days', I might have just made an extra column in the sql or did a string cat in the SQL and provided the value via prepared statement's setString() api prior to executing the query.    I think I can probably do this in JPA too; but doesn't seem the 'JPA way' (whatever that it is).

I thought of using an AttributeConverter on that column.   But I couldn't really figure out how to specify runtime data to be used by the instance(s) of the converter that would be created and used by JPA.

I thought about using an EntityListener and @PostLoad and doing the prefixing during postLoad.    But there again, wasn't sure how I would get my runtime data/prefix into the listener instance that JPA would use while loading data from my query.

I thought about following the EntityListener path but using a CDI inject of my prefix using a producer and a qualifier.   But I am writing for SE not EE and I am on the fence about running this standalone app as a CDI/SE java program.

So how would one use the declarative (annotation based)  converters or entitylisteners  from JPA but have a hook to initialize the converter or listener instance?

Or is there some way of;  prior to creating the query or prior to getting the result set; attaching an already initialized attribute converter or entity listener?

JPA 2.1 API
Java 17
Would like to avoid binding directly (in code) to a lib like the eclipslink code  (use only JPA citerium

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the prefix as a static variable somewhere in your program, and use that prefix in your listener via a static variable?

Comment: I guess I could.   But then I was trying to not couple the entity listener to any of the CLI processing code or for that matter really any other part of the program except the entity involed.  Or atleast limit the coupling.    I guess that part wasn't clear in my original SO question.     I do think this would work.